# LIKE operator for array value of column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have simple table with columns x and y.
These columns contains SQL-like patterns for matching.
Column x is array of varchar (VARCHAR[])
Column y is simple string (VARCHAR)

As example:

first row:

```
x                         y
{'asd','sdf%','%er%'}     %er%
```

I have this query:

```
SELECT x, 'ters' LIKE ANY("x"), y, 'ters' LIKE "y" FROM s
```

So the result of this query is:

```
"{'asd','sdf%','%er%'}";f;"%er%";t
```

My trouble is:

Why does the `LIKE` operator work for Y but not for X.

How can I match by `VARCHAR[]`?

Comment: Post the exact output of `select x;`

Comment: it was written above.
select "x" from s;

"{'asd','sdf%','%er%'}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wrong input format for the array:

```
select x, 'ters' like any (x), x[3]
from (values
    ('{asd,sdf%,%er%}'::varchar[]),
    ($${'asd','sdf%','%er%'}$$)
) s(x);
           x           | ?column? |   x    
-----------------------+----------+--------
 {asd,sdf%,%er%}       | t        | %er%
 {'asd','sdf%','%er%'} | f        | '%er%'
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT