# Searching through PostreSQL array column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `slide_results` table which has `tags` array column:

```
tags character varying[] DEFAULT '{}'::character varying[]
```

I'm searching `slide_results` by tags in the following way:

```
select * from slide_results where array_to_string(tags, ',') ilike '%pro%';
```

Is there simpler way of doing that?

Comment: If the duplicate link does not work for you, then state why here and maybe your question can be reopened.

Comment: `select * from slide_results where tags @> ARRAY['pro']::varchar[]`

Comment: Other possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46047339/330315 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/45189568/330315